# Change numerical string to date format

Tags: r, character, insertion

I have the following dataframe with the date of 23/09/15 in a numerical string.

```
Date     Session
230915       2  
230915       2 
230915       2   
230915       2  
230915       2  
230915       2
```

I want to change the "Date" column so that it's "23/09/15". Easiest way I thought to do this was to insert "/" after character 2 and 4.

I tried doing it this way:

```
sub( '(?<=.{2})', '/', df$Date, perl=TRUE )
```

But got the error:

Error in data$Date : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Also tried editing the date format with:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(data1$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

The column came back with NA's. Why?

Comment: Try `as.Date(as.character(dat$Date), format="%d %m %y")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `dmy` from `lubridate`

```
v1 <- dmy(df1$Date)
v1
#[1] "2015-09-23" "2015-09-23" "2015-09-23" "2015-09-23" "2015-09-23" "2015-09-23"
```

It might be better to store it as `Date` format.  But, if the format needed is different

```
format(v1, "%d/%m/%y")
#[1] "23/09/15" "23/09/15" "23/09/15" "23/09/15" "23/09/15" "23/09/15"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="Date     Session
230915       2  ")  
gsub( '(..)\\B', '\\1/', df$Date )
# [1] "23/09/15"
```

or

```
(x <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format="%d%m%y"))
# [1] "2015-09-23"
format(x, "%d/%m/%y")
# [1] "23/09/15"
```

However, if `df` is a vector, then there is no `$` subsetting option:

```
df <- df$Date
gsub( '(..)\\B', '\\1/', df$Date )
# Error in df$Date : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what the gsub does there please?

Comment: It replaces all matches by the match and a forward-slash. A match is any two characters that are not followed by the empty string provided by the edge of a word.